# Merging fields of 2 tables as recordset not working

Tags: django, orm, django-models, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Org(models.Model):
    org_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    org_hood = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    

class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    is_self_managed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    orgs = models.ManyToManyField(Org, through='OrgToMember', default)
```

The above models are joined through the following model:

```
class OrgToMember(models.Model):
    org_to_member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org, unique=False)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, unique=False)
    member_since = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    is_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_self_managed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    notifications = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

A member has a balance in each Org they are in. They can be in many Orgs and Orgs can have many members. I am trying to bring back a list of records with the following fields related to a specific member:

```
org_name balance notifications
```

If I create a member object, I can list the orgs for the member like so:

```
m = Member.objects.get(pk=2)
m.orgs.values()
```

This will bring back just the fields in the Org model. Or, I can bring back the fields in OrgToMember like this:

```
m = Member.objects.get(pk=2)
m.orgtomember_set.values()
```

I can't seem to merge the 2 models and return the fields I need (org_name, balance, notifications). I am pretty sure it has something to do with the relationships I created between my models or the fact that I need to be using the 'select_related' function, but that does not seem to work no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could start with OrgToMember instance and access Org from that point. You don't even have to access Member anymore as all you need to know is it's pk, and I assume you know that.

```
otms = OrgToMember.objects.filter(member__pk=2)
for otm in otms:
    org_name = otm.org.org_name
    balance = otm.balance
    notifications = otm.notifications
    print org_name, balance, notifications
```